# is it possible select the hit field of the search query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to search on both `from_a` and `from_alt` fields, but should select only the hit field(field which matches with search criteria) as `from_airport`

sample table :

```
+--------+-----------------+
| from_a |      from_alt   |
+--------+-----------------+
| FRA    | BER,MUQ         |
| JFK    | CAL,FRA         |
+--------+-----------------+
```

sample query for normal selection:

```
select from_a as from_airport
from details
where from_a like 'FRA%'
   or from_alt like 'FRA%';
```

But what I need to select is the hit field as `from_airport`

for this example result should be like,

```
+--------------+
| from_airport | 
+--------------+
| FRA          | 
| CAL,FRA      | 
+--------------+
```

Is that possible with normal mysql query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE`:

```
select CASE 
         WHEN from_a like 'FRA%' THEN from_a 
         WHEN from_alt like 'FRA%' THEN from_alt
       END as from_airport  
from details 
where from_a like 'FRA%' or from_alt like 'FRA%';
```

If both fields match, then `from_a` takes precedence over `from_alt`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union`:

```
select from_a as from_airport from details where from_a like 'FRA%'
union
select from_alt from details where from_alt like 'FRA%'
```